# Accessing Android Default Paste Option?

Tags: android, copy-paste

In Android using Clipboard classes I can get copied data.

But Is there any way to **access the Android default paste option**.

So,I want display the message list (linked with paste option) which are copied in my application.**So user can select multiple recently copied data** and paste it.
Means I want to access the android system paste option.

**In Short,Whenever user trying to paste text data in any application presented in his mobile,should display pop up contains message list.**

Like in below image

[image]

So,How I can do this in Android?

Comment: I just know that,one method is there related with paste option which can be override.but,I don't know that method name.Is there any method related to paste option which will be override on paste option?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Clipboardmanager like given below in code.Thanks

```
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager)
                getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        clipboard.getPrimaryClip();
```

Comment: this gives me copied data

Comment: i want to access paste option

Comment: try it. this give the data in clipboard for more information checkout ClipBoardManger class of android.

Comment: paste option comes by default on longpress on edittext but if you want customisation plase a button in your option list and use this code to get the copied data and set it where ever you want.

Comment: you have any code related this  means how i can customize my app to place button